# System configuration for Jupyter Notebook to connect to remote Oracle database

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, windows-10, database-connection, cx-oracle

### Summary

I'm having difficulties configuring my Oracle Install Client on my desktop so that I may connect my Jupyter Notebook to a remote Oracle database.

### Things I've Tried

I've tried several debugging solutions from Stack Overflow, GitHub bug reports, reading/re-reading/re-re-reading Oracle documentation for Windows 10 setup, Youtube videos, random articles online, and I've even asked around my company for help.

I don't think it is my code, I think I configured the Oracle Instant Client incorrectly on my desktop.

I've confirmed that I'm using 64bit Python, 64bit Windows, and installed the 64bit Oracle Install Client.

I downloaded the Basic Package and the SQL*Plus Package from here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html
I then extracted the individual contents of those packages into C:/Oracle/instantclient_19_3
It does not have a *setup.exe* file within the downloaded packages.

I then created a User variable -

Variable: *ORACLE_HOME*

Value: *C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_3*

And I updated the PATH System variable to include the Environment Variable: 
*C:\Oracle\instantclient_19_3*

(I've also tried to only use the value of C:\Oracle which was unsuccessful)

### My Code and Resulting Error

```
import cx_Oracle

CONN_INFO = {
    'host': 'my-host',
    'port': my-port,
    'user': 'my-user',
    'psw': 'my-password',
    'service': 'my-service',
}

CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f23d819d7d09> in <module>
     11 CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)
     12 
---> 13 connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)

DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
```

### Desired Result

I should be able to create the connection, without an error, so that I can then run a SQL Query.

Comment: You said you put the files in `C:/Oracle/instantclient_19_3`. You said you set the value of `ORACLE_HOME` to `C:\Oracle\installclient_19_3`. There seems to be a mismatch between the directory names. ???

Comment: Don't set ORACLE_HOME when you are using Instant Client.  Restart terminals, Jupyter etc after setting PATH.  Triple check you did actually get the 64-bit Instant Client, not the 32-bit one.

Comment: @BobJarvis thanks for catching that! That was a typo in this post and I've now updated it. The variables I had on my desktop were correctly set to "instantclient"

Comment: @Christopher Jones thank you for your help! I removed ORACLE_HOME and then reset my terminals and Jupyter Notebooks. I was able to successfully connect!  Do you know why I needed to remove ORACLE_HOME? I'm not really sure what that is doing. Also, would you post this comment as an answer so that I can mark this as the correct answer for others?

Comment: Instant Client will ignore ORACLE_HOME.  But setting it is a sign that your environment may be screwed up.  And you don't want to have a clash between libraries in a real ORACLE_HOME DB installation and Instant Client.  Better to be safe than sorry, so I suggest unsetting it.  I suspect restarting the terminals & notebooks was your real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart terminals, Jupyter etc after setting PATH.

Triple check you did actually get the 64-bit Instant Client, not the 32-bit one.

Don't set ORACLE_HOME when you are using Instant Client, since this is not needed.  And setting it is a sign to me that you may have other environment problems.